# How to be back on main class panel from panels of different class?

Tags: java, swing

I have two classes one is main class and other is pro class. The main class has introductory panel which further shows the panel of pro class. The second panel of pro class has "Home" button which needs to show the main class panel. please tell me how do I make "Home" button work?

```
class proMain extends JPanel {
    JPanel pan2 = new JPanel();
    JButton b1, b2, b3;
    CardLayout lay = new CardLayout();

    public void pshow() {

        // First Panel
        pan.setBackground(Color.red);
        b1 = new JButton("Next");
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Next")) {
                    pan2.setVisible(true);
                    pan.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });

        pan.add(b1);

        // Second Panel
        b2 = new JButton("Previous");
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Previous")) {
                    pan.setVisible(true);
                    pan2.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
        b3 = new JButton("Home");
        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (ae.getActionCommand() == "Home") {
                    //
                }
            }
        });
        pan2.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        pan2.add(b2);
        pan2.add(b3);
        pan.setVisible(true);
        pan2.setVisible(false);
        add(pan);
        add(pan2);
    }
}
```

Above class is proMain class and the main class is:

```
public class proDis {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("CrdLay");
        JPanel pan3 = new JPanel();
        JButton b = new JButton("Next");
        CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
        fr.setLayout(cl);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Next")) {
                    pan3.setVisible(false);
                    proMain pm = new proMain();
                    pm.pshow();
                    pm.setLayout(cl);
                    fr.add(pm);
                    pm.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
        pan3.setBackground(Color.gray);
        pan3.add(b);
        fr.setSize(100, 300);
        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.add(pan3);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have set `pan3.setVisible(false)` ... so just reverse that. Show this one and hide `pm`. Not sure hwo this will work with CardLayout ... not used it in a long time

Comment: or you call `proDis.main(args);` which will also bring you back to your main frame xD

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, that is not a good idea... this will generate a new Frame here, but could do much more work than expected in general project (loading Properties, basic validation, ...)

Comment: and that is the reason why i normally create gui not in the main method

Comment: Your work may get ugly if you are relying on multiple JFrames. You may consider other options such as JTabbedPane (if you have the time) .

Comment: @AxelH Thank you Sir for your response. Can you please tell me more about your suggestion how this will help?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Thank you for your response Sir. I tried your method but it showing error on "args" what will be args here?

Comment: args is a `String[] array`. there is no need to fill it with content, but as you surely read its not the best way to do it that way

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes, sir I have read but I think there is no harm in trying this.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use a `CardLayout`, which is the correct approach. However, your implementation is incorrect.

The problem with your code is that you are not using the methods of the `CardLayout` to control which panel is being displayed. The `CardLayout` supports methods. like `next(...)` and `previous(...)` to sequentially move through all the panels and the method `show(...)` to display a specific panel.

So the first thing to do is give your panels a name when you add each panel to the layout. Then change your code to use the above methods to control which panel is being displayed. There is no need to play with the visibility of any panel, this is the job of the `CardLayout`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.